# getResourceAsStream() returns null

Tags: java, libgdx

I have the following problem

```
InputStream input = FileHandle.class.getResourceAsStream("/data/sounds/back.ogg");
```

returns null, but

```
InputStream input = FileHandle.class.getResourceAsStream("/data/sounds/back.png");
```

returns InputStream, also both files are in this folder. What can be wrong?

I'm using libgdx-0.9.6

Answer (score 2):

If your path starts with "/", java will search your file in the root of your file system.

If it is in your root folder, first of all, check if file exists:

```
ls -l /data/sounds/ | grep "back.ogg"
```

If it does not exists or you do not have permissions, then you have the answer.

If it exists, you could try another way to get its InputStream:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/data/sounds/back.ogg");
```

Comment: FileInputStream() returns it as InputStream, the problem is in libgdx function