# Get the directory inside the jar

Tags: java, file, jar, embedded-resource

How to get the directory inside the jar?

Let's say I have a jar called foo.jar, how can I make the jar be able to access a file that's like this `foo.jar!/text.txt`, whereas the class is like `foo.jar!/randomPackage/Main.class`?

I'm able to do that while still in eclipse, but then when I export the program into a jar, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use, e.g., [`java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to access the file. That will work either inside a jar or on the filesystem.

Comment: Right, though how can I get the parent directory, because this gets me the directory of the class?

Comment: Prefix the String you pass with `/`, to reference the root of the jar.

Comment: @Martin, there *is* no directory in a jar file -- files just have path names associated with them -- so it doesn't make sense to ask for access to it. There's no way to list the files in a jar file without opening it using something like `ZipInputStream`. But note that depending on the argument you pass it (read the Javadoc), the `getResource()` family of methods can find files "next to" class files, or at the root of a classpath entry, or indeed, anywhere along the classpath, inside a jar or out.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 main options.

1. `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("some/pkg/resource.properties");`
2. `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream.("/some/pkg/resource.properties");`

I just posted this more full post on it recently, [getResourceAsStream returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570523/getresourceasstream-returns-null/16571137#16571137)