# android can not get file from classpath

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, testing, android-syncadapter

I have a package that contains two files one java file that is a SyncAdapterTest and another file which is a json file.

I am following the same structure as the SyncAdapterTest in the sample app in the Android website. http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/BasicSyncAdapter.zip. With one exception rather than having a `String` variable with json assigned to it directly, I'd rather have the json in a seperate file as its too large and it makes the test unreadable, plus reusability.

I am pretty new to Android development and I have tried using `File` or `InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("sample.json")`. I keep getting the `InputStream` `null` and the `File.exists()` as `false`. Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Here is my code

```
public void testIncomingParsed() {
        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("sample.json");
        if (in != null) {
            Log.d("HOMERSIMPSON", "wooohoo");
            Log.d("HOMERSIMPSON", in.toString());
        } else {
            Log.d("HOMERSIMPSON", "dooooooooooh");
        }
    }
```

As you can imagine doooooh! is what I'm getting.

Comment: Check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16571046/2715073) might help you.