# How to set image using javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I got an error while using this code to set an image.
Also I put my image in src folder. I tried another ways but nothing worked for me.

```
Code:

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.geometry.Pos;
    import javafx.scene.Node;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.image.Image;
    import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
    import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class Clock extends Application{

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);

        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage ps) throws Exception {
            ps.setTitle("Analog Clock");
            ps.show();

            StackPane pane = new StackPane();

            pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

            ImageView image = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("analog.png")));
                    pane.getChildren().add(image);

            //Image img = new Image("analog.png");

            // ImageView iv1 = new ImageView();
            // iv1.setImage(img);

             Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
```

below are errors Every time I run the code.

```
Error:


    Exception in Application start method
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$50/14845382.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null
        at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at Clock.start(Clock.java:26)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$53/2934105.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/18503843.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/19884472.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/2180324.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/3326003.run(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
    Exception running application Clock
```

Help me to solve this issue.
thanks

Comment: Is the analog.png file in the same package like the clock class? If not, you need to add a slash in front of it like: `"/analog.png"`. This comes from the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) of `getResourceAsStream()` method.

Comment: Also note, that AFAIK you should close your stream yourself (eg. use a try-with-resources statement). Or in this case you might want use one of the other constructors which support resource paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `InputStream` is `null`. you should know that if your Image file is in your source folder then you should direct it to it. right click on your image and select `copy qualified name` and use that for example

i have a folder in my src folder-(package) called `files` and my image file is `default_profile_icon.png`, then i will use this code

```
new Image("/files/default_profile_icon.png",160,160,false,true)
```

the first parameter is what you look at, hope you get it now.

i do not know where your image is located,hence this answer

Answer (score 2):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null
...
at Clock.start(Clock.java:26)
```

You've got a NPE at line 26, which is the following line of code:

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("analog.png")));
```

The culprit is likely the reference to 
`analog.png`.  The system is failing to read the file from the location you're providing and `getResourceAsStream()` is returning a `null` value.

You can further determine this by breaking the line up as:

```
InputStream inStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("analog.png");
Image imageObject = new Image(inStream);
ImageView image = new ImageView(imageObject);
```

and confirm which line number is referenced by the new stack trace when you run Clock.

Confirm your file `analog.png` is accessible or correct the path / location of your image file along the path.  The rules for using `getResourceAsStream()` properly when it is returning `null` are summarized in [this Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570523/getresourceasstream-returns-null).