# What is the path to my .png in my project (java eclipse)?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to understand how java paths work in eclipse but I am terribly confused.
I have an image `troll.png` and I am using `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("troll.png"))` to access it.

Now, if I put `troll.png` in the same package as the classes I use it in, it works. But I want to place it in another folder, so I made a folder `resources` in the project, parallel to the `src` folder where I keep my classes.

How can I read an image from that folder? I've tried every path I could think of and none worked.

Answer (score 2):

> I made a folder 'resources' in the project, parallel to the 'src'
>   folder where I keep my classes. How can I read an image from that
>   folder?

Prefix the path with `/` in order to access the resources in the root directory. If you are not doing it, then you are just looking at package level, relative to the current package.

Here you go:

```
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/troll.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue can be solved as following:

```
ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("troll.png"));
```

Please see also: [getResourceAsStream returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570523/getresourceasstream-returns-null)