# Outbound (!) SSL connection Wildfly

Tags: ssl, wildfly, outbound

our Wildfly 8.1-Server needs to establish an outbound (!) LDAPS-connection to a server within the organization's network. This connection is only used to sync various application data.
Unfortunately, there's no documentation about Wildfly's outbound-only truststore. Every research I do just gives me results about enabling SSL for inbound connections.

How exactly can I add a certificate to Wildfly's truststore for outbound SSL connections? Is there any documentation about this? I'd be thankful for any help on this topic.

Comment: Do you plan on using some sort of Wildfly service to make the connection?

Comment: No, that's not necessary. A singleton bean is enough.

Comment: Perhaps put your certificate in a jar file or something? What I'm getting at is that I think that the Java SSL client just needs a property setting for where the file is. I don't think it needs to specifically interact with the container. I don't know whether the container has a "Trust Service' available to you, but I admit I never really played around with that stuff. files for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Found a solution; Take a look at my answer.

Comment: Looks about what I had in mind, the cert will be in you .war file somewhere and the classloader will find it. Mind you, it pays to understand when [getResourceAsStream returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570523/getresourceasstream-returns-null?lq=1), just in case it comes up.

Comment: Sure, but thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

Found two possible solutions. First the one i would not use:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",path_to_your_cacerts_file);
```

The second one I'd prefer:

```
public class LDAPSSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

private SSLSocketFactory actualSocketFactory;

public LDAPSSocketFactory() {

    InputStream certificateInputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("yourcert.pfx");

    try {

        KeyStore pkcs12 = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");

        pkcs12.load(certificateInputStream, "".toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

        tmf.init(pkcs12);

        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        ctx.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        actualSocketFactory = ctx.getSocketFactory();

    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

//Override methods by simply deligating them to the actualSocketFactory

}
```

And pass this as an JNDI param for ldap connections:

```
env.put("java.naming.ldap.factory.socket", "LDAPSSocketFactory");
```

Found all of this on StackOverflow, but I forgot where exactly, so I basically pasted their solution here.

Comment: Either of those should be a solution for you - WildFly is not involved in managing the outbound connections for you when you are invoking the APIs directly yourselves.