# Not able to load properties file from classpath

Tags: java, scala

I have an eclipse scala project which I am assembling with sbt. I want to add a properties file which I have tried placing in both the src and the target/scala/classes folders. I am not sure how to load this file in my program. This is my code:

```
val reader=this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ccm.properties") //Reading the properties file
val p=new Properties();  
p.load(reader);  
val maxDimension = p.getProperty("maxDimension").toInt
```

This is the exception I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.musigma.ind.invictus.ConvergentCrossMapping.main(ConvergentCrossMapping.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
    at com.musigma.ind.invictus.ConvergentCrossMapping$.<init>(ConvergentCrossMapping.scala:35)
    at com.musigma.ind.invictus.ConvergentCrossMapping$.<clinit>(ConvergentCrossMapping.scala)
    ... 1 more
```

UPDATE: This question is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570523/getresourceasstream-returns-null) as I am writing this code in a Scala object and I cannot use `this.class.getResourceAsStream(...)`

Comment: where in `src` did you place this file? The convention is `src/main/resources` which would be scanned into the classpath by default, is that where you put it?

Comment: @TzachZohar The resources directory in main was not present. I created it and placed the file there. I am still getting the same exception.

Comment: @StoyanDekov, since this is scala, there are differences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of java properties class, you can do it with  **ConfigFactory**. File must be located under resources directory.

```
var b = getClass.getResource("/test.properties").getPath
val externalConfig1 = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(b))

println(externalConfig1.getInt("maxDimension"))
```