# Youtube Data Api: Can't get the InputStreamContent to work

Tags: java, youtube-data-api

I try to make my own YouTube video uploader. My only problem right now is that I can't get the following line of code to work:

```
InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent(VIDEO_FILE_FORMAT, UploadVideo.class.getResourceAsStream(videopath));
```

Where VIDEO_FILE_FORMAT is

```
private static final String VIDEO_FILE_FORMAT = "video/*";
```

and videopath is the path of the selected video. For example:

```
C:\Users\totgezockt\Documents\api-samples-master\java\src\main\resources\sample-video.mp4
```

If I now try to upload the video it says that mediacontent is null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570523/getresourceasstream-returns-null,

Comment: @VladimirVagaytsev The solutions there don't work for me