# How to read file from src/main/resources relative in a JUnit test?

Tags: java, junit

I have a junit testcase and a file that I want to load during that test. The file is placed under `src/main/resources`, whereas the packages are named same as the java testfile:

```
src/test/java/my/path/to/FileTest.java
src/test/resource/my/path/to/test.txt
```

Usage:

```
public class FileTest {
    @Test
    public void testRead() {
        String content = IOUtils.toString(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());
        System.out.println(content);
    }
}
```

Exception when running the testcase in IDE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:113)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2272)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:1041)
```

What might be wrong here?

Comment: did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570523/getresourceasstream-returns-null?*

Comment: have to tried getResourceAsStream("/my/path/to/test.txt")?

Comment: @user7294900 yes but I'd like to prevent having to define the fully qualified package path.

Comment: @RC. yes but also `FileTest.class.getResourcAsStream("test.txt");` fails with NPE.

Comment: It should be `System.out.println(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("my/path/to/test.txt").getFile())).readLine());` **without** the leading `/`, or `System.out.println(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(this.getClass().getResource("/my/path/to/source.txt").getFile())).readLine());` **with** the leading `/`. BTW using java 8 here.

Comment: have you tried new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(this.getClass().getResource("test.txt").getFile()))) ?

Comment: @IlyaZinkovich gives also a NPE.

Comment: I take it my suggestion somehow also failed? If so, could you please share a [sscce](http://sscce.org) on github or something similar? I'm interested in this since on my end it worked fine.

Comment: @Morfic of course your solution works, **but** I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to provide the fully qualified package path (my/path/to).

Comment: I see, sorry I missed that part. Then how about the following ugly hack: `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(this.getClass().getPackage().getName().replace(".", "/") + "/" + "test.txt"`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended placing the testfiles directly into `/src/main/resources` without subpackage, and using.

`PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(new ClassPathResource(filename));`