# Null pointer when connecting to database

Tags: java

I am trying to connect to a database with phpMyadmin but I get an nullpointer in properties

Here is my code:

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        final String ip = prop.getProperty("database_ip");
        final String dir = prop.getProperty("database_dir");
        final String username = prop.getProperty("database_username");
        final String password = prop.getProperty("database_password");

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No suitable driver found");
        }
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + ip + "/" + dir, username, password);
    }
```

and here is where the nullpointer happens:

```
private Properties getPropertyFile(String path) {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try {
            prop.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return prop;
    }
```

and here is my map structure:
[image]

Comment: What line is the NullPointerException coming from?

Comment: What `path` do you pass to `getPropertyFile`? Have you checked the resulting JAR file to ensure the resource is embedded in the JAR? (Not a experienced user with IntelliJ) is `resources` available to the classpath? Have you tried just `getClass().getResourceAsStream`?

Comment: see this answer for null returns from getResourceAsStream: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570523/getresourceasstream-returns-null

Comment: on this line: prop.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path));

Comment: "dbconfig.properties" this path @MadProgrammer

Comment: @nick Maybe try `/dbconfig.properties` or `/resources/dbconfig.properties`

Comment: @MadProgrammer nope same error:
 java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
 at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
 at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
 at dataaccess.init.Property.getPropertyFile(Property.java:22) ~[classes/:na]

Comment: Basically what it's trying to tell you is, the results of `getClass(). getResourceAsStream(...)` is `null`, you need to determine why. I'm not experienced with IntelliJ, so I can't suggest how you might check/fix this