# getResourceAsStream returning null in Java 10

Tags: java, java-10

I have an application that was working with Java 1.8.0 162 and I'm in the process of upgrading it to Java 10. One of the issues I'm having is that

```
appProperties.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/application.properties")
```

started returning null in Java 10. Any ideas why? `appProperties` is defined like this:

```
appProperties = new Properties();
```

and this happens in a static method, in case that's relevant.

The file is present in `src/main/resources/application.properties`. This happens whether I'm running in from IntelliJ or from the jar produced by Maven.

I tried adding:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
       <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

to my `pom.xml` but that had no effect.

Printing the class path with:

```
System.getProperty("java.class.path")
```

yields, as the first entry:

```
C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\Dashman\code\dashman\target\classes
```

which contains application.properties.

Comment: will this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570523/getresourceasstream-returns-null

Comment: does the javadoc for [ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) makes any sense to you?

Comment: @ochi: I'm not using the class of the class, so, it should, I should be using the correct class loader.

Comment: @Klaimmore: sort of. I see the module system might be into play, so, I'm going to read up on that, but I'm not using `getSystemResourceAsAStream()` nor the system class loader.

Comment: If you open the jar, where is the file?

Comment: What does `System.out.println(appProperties.getClass().getResource("/"))` yield?

Comment: Unable to reproduce it. I have two different setup for JDK 8 and JDK 10, both the place I use idea intelliJ ad maven. I quickly tested it, I couldn't reproduce it.

Comment: @cricket_007: in the root of the jar.

Comment: ```java version "10" 2018-03-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10+46)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10+46, mixed mode)```

Comment: @SeverityOne: also null.

Comment: in your IDEA can you print classpath entries by `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` and for each of the entry go out to terminal and see if it contains `application.properties` file at the root of those entries.

Comment: @JigarJoshi: I added that to the question. Yes, application.properties is there.

Comment: @popeno Did you lunch your application from module code? If not did you try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution although I don't entirely understand why this works an the problematic line doesn't, but this works:

```
Application.class.getResourceAsStream("/application.properties")
```

where `Application` is just a class in my app.

Maybe this is related to the answer pointed to by [ochi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49702287/getresourceasstream-returning-null-in-java-10/49702453#comment86418378_49702287), and `Application.class` is using *my* class loader and `appProperties.getClass()` is using the system class loader. But why does it behave differently on differently on Java 8 vs 10 is not something that is apparent.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it's the same issue... still weird, nonetheless

Comment: Just call `getClass` from any non-static method.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar: I need the value in a static method.

Comment: Then use the class name.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar: that's what I already did and documented with my answer here.

Answer (score 9):

The class of that variable is a system class and it is loaded by a different class loader.

You should use one of your *own* classes.

Comment: Right. `appProperties.getClass().getResourceAsStream(...)` is the equivalent of `Properties.class.getResourceAsStream(...)` so it locates the resource related to java/util/Properties. Moving to `Application.class.getResourceAsStream(...)` so that the resource is related relative to the application class is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error while using Intellij and the fix was that I needed to add the file format of the particular resource I intend to fetch. Navigate CRTL+ALT+s or settings->compiler->resource patterns:
Enter the file extension into that field. Click apply, then okay