# How to find path to a picture when it's sent to another computer

Tags: java, image, gradle, packaging

I'm currently making an executable JAR file which I want to be able to send to other computers. I have a loading/splash screen at the start at the program which uses a picture from my computer.

I'm currently using gradle to create the JAR file maybe that could be used?

Otherwise, I was thinking that I would send a zip-file containing the jar file and the picture and then in someway write the path in such a way so that it always finds the picture?

This is how I get the picture for my program.

```
new ImageIcon("/Users/UserA/Desktop/SheetsQuickstart/AD3.gif")
```

Answer (score 3):

Put your image file under a package `(com.myproject.images)` in your project and refer it like below:-

```
new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("images/AD3.gif"));
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't really understand how to do this? Where do I create this package if I'm using Gradle? I'm very new to using Gradle and packaging in general.

Comment: @Jordan at the top of your code above imports: **package com.myPackageName.images**

Answer (score 0):

Put the file containing your icon in your classpath (i.e. with your classes in your jar file) and use `getResourceAsStream` to access your image as a bytestream when you need it.

Note that this is notoriously hard to get right the first time.  You might want to look at [getResourceAsStream returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570523/getresourceasstream-returns-null) if you run into trouble.