# How to make a resource file available in a jar?

Tags: java, jar, embedded-resource

I have a jar and resource files are in the jar root directory. Inside the code I have:

```
Kernel.class.getResourceAsStream(resource);
```

I start the application as

```
java -cp myjar.jar com.mycompany.MyClass
```

However,  the resource is not found.

Comment: Jar files have a "class-path" manifest entry which defines the class path Java should use to find dependencies. I believe `-cp` will override this, but it's been so long since I tried anything like this I could be wrong.  Besides, `-cp` is only defining a single entry, it should be listing ALL the Jar's, which why it's better to use the Jar `class-path` manifest entry

Comment: This might very well be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570523/getresourceasstream-returns-null

Comment: Please show output of `jar tvf myjar.jar`  for the resource files.  Also be certain you have a leading "/" in your `resource`.

Comment: `Kernel.class.getResourceAsStream(resource);` Not nearly enough information to help solve this. What is the value of `resource`? What is the listing of the Jar content (see comment of @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen)? For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to precede the resource name by slash "/".  Then finding the resource in the jar root directory works fine

Answer (score 1):

You need your current directory in your classpath.

Linux:

```
java -cp myjar.jar:. com.mycompany.MyClass
```

Windows:

```
java -cp myjar.jar;. com.mycompany.MyClass
```

Comment: Even with `and resource files are in the jar root directory` ?

Comment: I was wondering because I read it as the root of the jarfile. OP should probably add some more info to the question.