# getResourceAsStream() search for file

Tags: java, inputstream

I need help to make `String.class.getResourceAsStream()` work in my application.

This is my tree directory:

```
\src 
|--java
|    |--it.x.y.z.q
|                |-- Main.java 
|                |-- config
|                    |-- ConfigHandler.java
|--resources
   |--config
      |--file.properties
```

The `Main.java` file contains the `main()` function. In the `ConfigHandler.java` file the is the function that actually calls `String.class.getResourceAsStream(path)`.

From similar question, I've read that `getResourceAsStream()` search for the file in the same folder where the Class is.

So, for me, the path should be: `..\..\..\..\..\..\..\resources\config\file.properties`. I'm working with Windows as OS, so I need to put double backslashes, I've done it.

Anyways, running

`InputStream is7 =  String.class.getResourceAsStream("..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\resources\\config\\file.properties")`

I get a null item. Why ?

How can I make this work without moving my files?

Comment: You're making incorrect assumptions about what `getResourceAsStream` does. It doesn't access files on the filesystem. It accesses resources (and classes) **on the classpath**. You should use `getResourceAsStream("/config/file.properties")` (assuming the content of the `resources` folder is on the root of the classpath, as what is common convention).

Comment: In any case you get `null` because - as the API doc says - _"`null` if no resource with this name is found"_. Also, `String.class.getResourceAsStream` is not guaranteed to see your resources (depends on the exact classloader hierarchy), generally you should use a class in the same application/library.

Comment: The `resources` folder is at the same level of the `java` folder. Since I'm in Windows I should use \\ istead /, right? In both cases it didn't work.

Comment: No. A resource is not something on the filesystem (though it might ultimately be obtained from the filesystem). It is something on the classpath, and the classpath uses `/` as the separator. And depending on how this is built and run, the actual files used might be somewhere else (e.g. in some temporary `build` or `out` folder, or even already packaged in a JAR).

Comment: Possible duplicates: [How do I load a file from resource folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749192/how-do-i-load-a-file-from-resource-folder), [getResourceAsStream returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570523/getresourceasstream-returns-null) (and many others)

Comment: Ok, I've understood how it works. So if I set correctly my classpath I should be able to find my file.properties. Now the question is: since my classpath variable is not set how should I set it? And how can I make this work in a different machine?

Comment: If the question is different you should post a different question, but search first, because I'm sure there are already countless questions about setting the classpath.

Comment: Ok, I made it work! I just changed `String.class.getResourceAsStream("/config/file.properties")` with `ConfigHandler.class.getResourceAsStream("/config/file.properties")`.